# SQL Query Optimization with GUID and Varchar column in its where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I am trying to optimize the below query.

The query is working fine, but taking huge time to get the result.
Data is huge in our tables
MessageCorrelationId is a GUID
OrginatingEventName is varchar(50)

Currently no index is created, just wondering that Non-Clustered Index on MessageCorrelationId or/and OrginationEventName will help or not.

```
Set @StartDate = DATEADD (hh , -4 , Getdate() )  
Set @EndDate = Getdate()

Set @OriginatingEventName = 'WareHouseForwardFlow'

Select top 1 @OriginSystemName = OriginSystemName  From WorkFlow
Select @StepCount=count(*) from WorkFlow where OriginatingEventName=@OriginatingEventName and OriginSystemName=@OriginSystemName

;WITH Success_CTE 
    AS
    (
        Select count(*) as 'CountSteps',MessageCorrelationId 
        from Activity  
        Where OriginatingEventName=@OriginatingEventName 
        AND CreatedDate >= @StartDate  and ErrorFlag=0 Group By MessageCorrelationId
        Having  count(*) >= @StepCount
    ),
    cte_lead AS
    (
        SELECT A.MessageCorrelationId,BridgeName,ServiceName,OriginSystemName,CreatedDate,ErrorFlag,ErrorMessage,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.MessageCorrelationId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS rn
            from Activity A
            Inner Join Success_CTE B On A.MessageCorrelationId = B.MessageCorrelationId
    )
    SELECT * FROM cte_lead WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Can you post the execution plan?  Have you tried replacing the first CTE with an insert into a temp table, then writing your second CTE against that? As for whether creating an index will help - you have access to your system, we don't. Create indexes in a test copy of your database and evaluate the results.

Comment: Consider an index including `CreatedDate`. Also, a partial or filtered index `WHERE ErrorFlag=0` http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/344/indexes/23954/partial-or-filtered-index#t=201610051725117390168

Comment: Tip: Make a single call to `GetDate()` and then use that value to calculate anything else you need. That ensures that the values are consistent.

Comment: @HABO great tip: First
`Set @ EndDate = Getdate()` then `Set @ StartDate = DATEADD (hh , -4 ,@ EndDate )`

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is

```
Select MessageCorrelationId,BridgeName,ServiceName,OriginSystemName,CreatedDate,ErrorFlag,ErrorMessage
from (
   select *, 
     COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MessageCorrelationId) as CountSteps,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MessageCorrelationId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS rn
   from Activity 
   where OriginatingEventName=@OriginatingEventName 
        AND CreatedDate >= @StartDate  and ErrorFlag=0 
) t
where CountSteps >= @StepCount and rn=1;
```